# Merge one feature stream commit to another

Tags: git

I had an old feature stream work for which was parked due to some missing functionality. Later once we had it I created a new feature stream and made my changes their and created a pull request instead of using the old feature stream for which we also have a pull request raised.

How can I merge the new feature stream commit changes to old feature stream?

Comment: I'm assuming feature stream is a branch you made? Please may you add any commands you used and their output?

Comment: We have a common develop repo - both of my old and new feature streams are cloned from same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From which branch did you create your new feature branch? If it was old feature branch, just merge your new feature branch into the old feature branch. 
The pull request of old feature branch will now also have changes after the merge. 
At this point, you won't be needing a pull request for new feature branch.

```
(old-feature-branch)> git merge new-feature-branch

(old-feature-branch)> git push
```

Comment: My old and latest feature branches were created from develop repo - so both old and new branches were branched out from a common repo. I tried to execute the command as mentioned but it stated - merge 'new branch' - not something we can merge

Comment: As long as both the old and new branches are in sync with your develop branch, git merge new-feature branch into old-feature branch should work. If for some reason, you do not wish to do a merge, you can cherry-pick individual commits from new-feature branch to old-feature-branch. It allows you to choose commits that you would like to add to old-feature-branch. This way you can choose all of the commits related to your feature to be cherry-picked. Merging is more straight forward though.

Comment: Thanks again - but note that I have checked in my code in both old and new feature streams

Comment: Please let me know the command to cherry pick commits made in my new feature stream?

Comment: its git cherry-pick <commit-hash>

Comment: I saw git logs of new stream and was able to merge the commits however the merge always stated me the same error - not something we can merge